# How can I hide a custom field if it's a particular value?

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements, logic, echo

I have a custom field in Wordpress for time which I'm trying to hide if the time field is '12:00 AM'.

I have tried the following which ended up hiding all time fields.

```
<?php if(trim(get_field('time'))=='12:00am') echo('style="display:none;"'); ?>
```

Comment: You'll need to supply some more of the surrounding code for us to see how it interacts

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation ( https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/time-picker/ ) I can see there is "display format" and "return format".

If you have set the return format to be like in the screenshot of "The time picker field settings" (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AdvancedCustomFields/docs/master/assets/acf-time-picker-field-settings.png) there is a space between the numbers and the "am".

Get rid of the `trim()`, don't think you need it here (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_words/).

So it should look like:

`if(get_field('time') == "12:00 am")` with a blank space betweem 00 and am.

If not working, make sure you set the right "return format" in the settings of your custom field.